# Semantic UI rating onRate()

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

Can someone please give me an example of the `onRate()` callback function (http://semantic-ui.com/modules/rating.html#/settings) for the rating widget in Semantic UI. I have tried everything :(

```
$('.ui.rating').rating('onRate(rating_changed())');
$('.ui.rating').rating().onRate(rating_changed());
$('.ui.rating').rating().onRate('rating_changed()');
etc ...
```

I don't know whether it should be used in javascript or in the div for the rating (`<div class="ui rating">`. Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use the [setting API](http://semantic-ui.com/module.html#/settings):

```
$('.ui.rating')
  .rating('setting', 'onRate', function(value) {
      // your amazing code here
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you. Perfect! This should really be in the documentation.

Comment: Why is this not documented??

Answer (score 5):

Something like this

```
$('.ui.rating')
    .rating({
        maxRating: 5,
        onRate: function (rating) {
            console.log(rating)
        }
    });
```